# Isomorphism of a vector space with $R^n$ and the role of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

It is often stated that a choice of a basis for a vector space over $R$ gives an isomorphism between $V$ and $R^n$. However, I am having a hard time showing this and confused over some issues. For simplicity, let's stick to a two-dimensional space $V$. Let's choose a basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$ for the vector space. Then we have the linear map $\phi: R^2 \to V; \phi(v_1,v_2)=v_1 e_1+v_2 e_2$. To prove the isomorphism between $R^2$ and $V$, I need to construct a map $\phi^{-1}: V\to R^2: \phi^{-1} \phi=Identity$. I don't see any obvious way to construct such a map. However, if there is an inner product (denoted here by ".") on $V$, we can construct such a map in the following way. Suppose $e_1,e_2$ is an orthonormal basis. We then set $\phi^{-1}: V\to R^2; \phi^{-1}(v)=(e_1.v, e_2.v)$. It is obvious that $\phi^{-1}\phi(v_1,v_2)=(v_1,v_2)$. So my question is, is it true that we need an inner product and the existence of an orthonormal basis to prove the isomorphism between $V$ and $R^2$?
Or I have misunderstood something here?

**Edit:**
I also would like to mention that this question originated from noticing the fact that although a given vector can be written as $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$, there is no natural way to find the coefficients $v_1,v_2$. The inner product seems to determine the values of $v_1,v_2$.

Comment: Send your basis to a basis. That‘s induces an isomorphism.

Comment: +1 for the edit. That's true the inner product gives you a simple method to "pick" the suitable coefficients

Answer (score 2):

The inner product is not relevant to the question.

In order that $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to V$ is an isomorphism it is necessary and sufficient that it is injective and surjective (besides being linear, of course).

Since $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a spanning set, the map is surjective.

Since $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is linearly independent, the map is injective.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an inner product. For $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ to be a basis of the finite-dimensional vectorspace $V$ (by definition of a basis or as a consequence of it being a maximal linearly independent set) there exists for every vector $v\in V$ a $\textbf{unique}$ $n$-tuple $$\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \cdot\\\cdot\\\cdot\\v_n\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
such that $v=\sum_{j=1}^nv_je_j$ and you define $\phi^{-1}(v)=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \cdot\\\cdot\\\cdot\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$.
Now it is easy to check that $\phi\circ\phi^{-1}=id_{V}$ and $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi=id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

This might be where the confusion comes in.

Given a basis $\{e_1, e_2 \}$ for $V$, this automatically gives us a [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$ of the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) $V^*$.

**Aside:** Note that it is NOT the case that "$e_1$ is dual to $\omega_1$ and $e_2$ is dual to $\omega_2$", instead the *entire set* $\{e_1, e_2\}$ "is dual to" the *entire set* $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$. E.g. choosing another basis of $V$ with one of the vectors still the same, $\{e_1, f_2\}$, we could get an entirely different dual basis $\{\nu_1, \nu_2\}$, $\nu_1 \not= \omega_1$ and $\nu_2 \not=\omega_2$. **/Aside**

Anyway, the isomorphism $V \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by the action of this dual basis, namely a vector $v \in V$ is identified with $(\omega_1(v), \omega_2(v)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. No inner product involved.

Now, at the same time, in identifying this isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have also identified the information needed to specify an inner product (or at least a non-degenerate bilinear form) on $V$.

This is by combining two observations:

1. A choice of isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ [is equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) specifying a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$ (inner products being a special case).
2. Choosing a basis for a vector space $V$ and a basis for a vector space $W$ of the same dimension allows one to specify an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$.

In this case (assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional) the vector space $W$ is the dual space $V^*$. The basis we chose for $V^*$ is the dual basis $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$, and so we can define an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ by identifying $e_1$ with $\omega_1$ and $e_2$ with $\omega_2$. At the same time, this isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ determines a unique inner product on $V$ (namely one for which the basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is orthonormal).

**TL;DR** the isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not require an inner product on $V$, but rather the isomorphism *does* define a unique choice of inner product on $V$.

(Replacing "inner product" with "nondegenerate bilinear form" as necessary, although I think the nondegenerate bilinear form defined this way is guaranteed to be positive definite, hence an inner product.)