# How/why does definition of eigenvalue/vector implicitly require a choice of inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, definition, multilinear-algebra

I forget exactly where, but I've heard/read multiple times it be mentioned that defining eigenvalues/vectors implicitly requires a choice of inner product.

> **Question:** Is it more correct to say that "the definition of eigenvalues/vectors ***of a linear map*** $L : R^n \to R^n$ does not depend on a choice of inner product" but that "the definition of eigenvalues/vectors ***of a matrix*** $M \in R^{n \times n}$ does implicitly depend on a choice of inner product"?

Specifically, I don't see how the definition of eigenvalues/vectors of a linear function depends in any way on choosing an inner product. The statement $L(v) = c v$ makes sense / is well defined regardless of what inner product does or does not exist on the vector space $V$ such that $v \in V$ and $L: V \to V$.

I know that a choice of inner product (or more generally any non-degenerate bilinear form, inner products being positive definite special case) is equivalent to a choice of isomorphism between a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$. (For example compare the notion of "[musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism)".)

I also know that the space of linear maps $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ is isomorphic to $V^* \otimes V$. Taking matrices to be "fully contravariant", the space of matrices would be isomorphic to $V \otimes V$, and thus to define an isomorphism (correspondence) between linear functions $V^* \otimes V$ and matrices $V \otimes V$, one requires an isomorphism between $V^*$ and $V$, i.e. a choice of inner product (or more generally non-degenerate bilinear form).

Hence we would expect that notions like "eigenvalues/vectors of a linear map" that don't depend on a choice of inner product for $V$ end up depending on a choice of inner product for $V$ when we define their "matrix analogues".

Is this correct? Or is there a deeper / subtler way in which the definition of eigenvalues / eigenvectors depends on an implicit choice of inner product such that the dependence still exists even when defining those concepts with respect to linear functions?

Related question: [Does matrix multiplication require an inner product space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658823/does-matrix-multiplication-require-an-inner-product-space)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't depend on having an inner product.

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: The answer in your link states the point of confusion: Matrix multiplication does not require an inner product, but choosing bases induces a natural choice for one that is often used when discussing matrix multiplication. However, this is not necessary when discussing eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @Randall It was in a lecture and/or writings of members / alumni of a specific research group, but given that I don't remember a specific lecture or paper I could point to making the claim, I don't want to name the group or people involved here. Especially because I may be misremembering.

Comment: Since the notions of eigenvalue and eigenvector apply also to matrices in fields where no inner product can be defined (such as finite fields), I think the answer to your question should be obvious.

Comment: @user1551 I didn't know/realize that inner products can't be defined for vector spaces over finite fields (I guess it's the non-degenerate condition that can't be satisfied due to torsion?) or that eigenvalues/vectors were studied in that context. This is a helpful observation that would not be obvious to everyone. The research I had in mind where this was mentioned was about real- and complex-valued tensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer.

The definitions of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear map from a  vector space $V$ to itself are independent of any choice (including none) of an inner product on $V$.

If you choose a basis for $V$ then you can reason about the eigenvectors and values of the matrix corresponding to a linear map. That's still independent of any notion of an inner product.

However, choosing a basis implicitly defines an inner product since vectors "become" $n$-tuples (assuming $V$ is finite dimensional). Then it makes sense to discuss the relationship between eigenvectors and the inner product - for example, to ask whether eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Would it make sense to argue though that choosing a basis for $V$ "is equivalent to" choosing an inner product for $V$? In the sense that doing so uniquely specifies a basis (the dual basis) for $V^*$, hence an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ (one derived by identifying the chosen basis for $V$ with the dual basis of $V^*$) hence a non-degenerate bilinear form for $V$? I've made that argument before (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4854448/606791) but I don't think I've ever read it in any introductory linear algebra texts before, where one would expect to see the argument if i was true

Comment: Choosing a basis defines an inner product, but not conversely. Once you choose an inner product there are many bases (the orthonormal ones) that "define" the same inner product.